# Using nested for-loop to generate a table of numbers

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I try to write a function in which print this output:

```
1
2 4
3 6 9
4 8 12 16
5 10 15 20 25
```

I wrote this code, but I'm not getting the desired output:

```
rows = 5;
% there are 5 rows
for i=1:rows
    for j=1:i
        b=i*j;
    end
    fprintf('%d\n',b)
end
```

How to I need to correct this algorithm or can you tell me, if there are any other alternate methods to solve this?

Comment: Use proper indention and you will notice the obvious error. Your inner loop is not printing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by *"print"*, but this is how you could start:

```
%// initial vector
a = 1:5;

A = tril( bsxfun(@plus,a(:)*[0:numel(a)-1],a(:)) )
%// or 
A = tril(a.'*a)   %'// thanks to Daniel!
mask = A == 0
out = num2cell( A );
out(mask) = {[]}
```

---

```
A =

     1     0     0     0     0
     2     4     0     0     0
     3     6     9     0     0
     4     8    12    16     0
     5    10    15    20    25

out = 

    [1]      []      []      []      []
    [2]    [ 4]      []      []      []
    [3]    [ 6]    [ 9]      []      []
    [4]    [ 8]    [12]    [16]      []
    [5]    [10]    [15]    [20]    [25]
```

To print it to a file, you can use.

```
out = out.'; %'
fid = fopen('output.txt','w')
fprintf(fid,[repmat('%d \t',1,n) '\r\n'],out{:})
fclose(fid)
```

and you get:

[image]

just for the command window:

```
out = out.'; %'
fprintf([repmat('%d \t',1,n) '\r\n'],out{:})
```

will be sufficient. Choose your desired delimiter, if you don't like `'\t'`.

---

If you insist on a nested for loop, you can do it like this:

```
rows = 5;
% there are 5 rows
for ii = 1:rows
    for jj = 1:ii
        b = ii*jj;
        if ii <= jj
           fprintf('%d \n',b)
        else
           fprintf('%d ',b)
        end
    end  
end
```

---

displays:

```
1 
2 4 
3 6 9 
4 8 12 16 
5 10 15 20 25
```

Comment: No need for `bsxfun` here, `A=tril(a'*a)`

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the hint, included!

Comment: Thanks thewaywewalk for assistance .. the above mentioned algorithm includes some function with which i am not familiar ... i want to make a script which will create the above mentioned table .... I want to make this script with using nested for loop only... kindly assist me in nested for loop only... thanks

Comment: thank you so much @thewaywewalk for the correct assistance..... :) it absolutely work